# How to create in Laravel one record and his many relationships in one view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, relationships

Let's asume that I'm going to create a Todo-List, each Todo-List has many items. So I want to know how in a single blade view I can register the name of the To-Do list and then below add multiple items. Then with a single submit button save first the todo list and then all the items on that list.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a form with an input for the name of the to-do list and using JS, add an additional to-do item when the user clicks on + or add or enter, whatever. When the submit button is clicked, have the form send a post request to Laravel to save the to-do name and items. Then redirect to a get request for adding another to-do list